# Merge many columns into one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have:

```
 A   B  'C'
'l' 'f' 'g'
's' 'y' 'l'
'v' 'W' 'q'
```

I would like

```
ABC
'lfg'
'syl'
'vWq'
```

It meands, I want to get all the columns int one, not a new, just one. I know I could merge it with'+' but I prefer somenthing more simple, must exist.

Thanks

Comment: `df.agg(''.join, axis=1)`

Comment: you can use pandas to do this as well,

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: `df.agg(''.join, axis=1).str.replace("'",'').rename('ABC').to_frame()`